# Why is a union mysql query over three tables faster than join on impossible where clauses?

Tags: mysql, database, join, union

My schema is set up such that I have three tables `player` `coach` and `manager` where all three have a foreign key to a table `employee` which contains not more than a single auto-incrementing id and a string `type` representing the type of employee they are ie. 'PLAYER' or 'COACH' or 'MANAGER'.

However, different employees have different ids based on the team they work for. So I have a lookup table `team_x_lookup` for each team (where x is the team number or name) which maps a team id to a global id. Also, I have a generated column within each `player` `coach` and `manager` table for each team which contains the team id, this column is indexed. This column will obviously be null if the employee is not on that team.

To fetch an employee from their team id I currently have two select statements

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
    LEFT JOIN player p ON (e.`type` = 'PLAYER' AND p.employee_id = e.id)
    LEFT JOIN coach c ON (e.`type` = 'COACH' AND c.employee_id = e.id)
    LEFT JOIN manager m ON (e.`type` = 'MANAGER' AND m.employee_id = e.id)
WHERE e.id = (
    SELECT employee_id FROM team_x_lookup t WHERE t.team_id = 6
);

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM player WHERE team_id = 6 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM coach WHERE team_id = 6
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM manager WHERE team_id = 6
) as emp;
```

I have indexes on everything I do a SELECT on. Running explain gives me these respectively:

```
1   PRIMARY e       const   PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE           PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY p       const   PRIMARY,employee_id _UNIQUE PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY c       const   PRIMARY,employee_id _UNIQUE PRIMARY 4   const   0   0.00    unique row not found
1   PRIMARY m       const   PRIMARY,employee_id _UNIQUE PRIMARY 4   const   0   0.00    unique row not found
2   SUBQUERY t      const   PRIMARY,team_id_UNIQUE      PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  

1   PRIMARY         <derived2>      ALL                                 6               100.00  
2   DERIVED         player          ref team_x_id_INDEX team_x_id_INDEX 5   const   1   100.00  Using index
3   UNION           coach           ref team_x_id_INDEX team_x_id_INDEX 5   const   1   100.00  Using index
4   UNION           manager         ref team_x_id_INDEX team_x_id_INDEX 5   const   1   100.00  Using index
N   UNION RESULT    <union2,3,4>    ALL                                                         Using temporary
```

I don't like the second way of doing this because it requires me to have potentially 20 more columns for each table. But, I don't understand how the union query is up to 50% faster than the lookup table query! Doesn't the union have to select on all three tables, whereas the cross reference query will notice that one of the three joins is possible and discard the other two?

I would like to know how to make the cross reference table faster, additionally because union requires me to select the same number of columns from each table in the union while each of my tables have a different number of columns that all should be returned.

EDIT

I have about 30,000 elements in the database and I am doing my timing by querying the first half of my data via the union and the second half via the join. My time comes out to roughly 3.9s for the union and 7.0s for the join.

Comment: Please give DDL. Read about and act on [mcve]. Search [so] re bad idea  "smart keys", encoding info in key values. team_x_lookup is also a bad idea, you are encoding info in table names. Just start with a straightforward design where all info is recorded as values on rows of tables. Each table has an associated *predicate* (sentence template) and holds rows that say something about the situation when column values are substituted for column names. PS Your use of NULL seems like it might be making your table way larger than necessary, with every row requiring an unnecessary calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make the first query more efficient by removing the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT e.* FROM employee e
INNER JOIN team_x_lookup t ON e.id = t.employee_id
LEFT JOIN player p ON (e.`type` = 'PLAYER' AND p.employee_id = e.id)
LEFT JOIN coach c ON (e.`type` = 'COACH' AND c.employee_id = e.id)
LEFT JOIN manager m ON (e.`type` = 'MANAGER' AND m.employee_id = e.id)
WHERE t.team_id = 6
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the query simpler but doesn't change the execution time

Comment: ok fair enough. often subqueries can be an issue but clearly not in this case.